# Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite ) but got object: You likely forgot to export

Tags: react-native, render

It show this error message whenever I try to import app.js file in my app.js file. How to overcome this problem...

[image: App.js]

[image: HeaderTabs.js]

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your import from:

```js
import HeaderTabs
```

to

```js
import {HeaderTabs}
```

And/or try to change your declaration to:

```js
const App = () => {

  return (

  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: showing same problem

Comment: It always shows Check the render method of 'App' in the mobile screen

Comment: It Again show the same problem . i add the code you told me to